# What theory is the person in this song talking about?

Tags: acoustics, vibrations

What he is talking about sounds interesting to me, and I would like to know more. But I need to know the name first.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ogn5FrVGtAg&hd=1

Comment: Please transcribe the lyrics--- link doesn't work.

Comment: I don't have acces to Youtube on this PC. But he basically is talking about how vibration gives form to objects. And how the form changes if the frequency changes.

Comment: He's talking about a lay-person mangled version of string theory, as Briane Greene describes it. It would not be recognizable to physicists as stated, but it would be recognizable to viewers of "The Elegant Universe" (bad popular show).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String theory, a-la Briane Greene's "The Elegant Universe" (which bears very little resemblence to actual string theory).